# link in the repeater first time only working inside the update panel control

Tags: asp.net

I have link buttons for showing gridview and list view and also I have paging using datalist control all these being within the updatepanel.

Paging and listview link button and gridview link button working fine in the first load but the problem is when I'm doing any action within update panel like moving to next page or change gridview to listview then the `<a>` tag link within the repeator control is not working.

I have order buton inside the repeator control this will give the modal pop up for quantity selection and  add to cart option but `<a>` tag not working it does not show modal.

This `<a>` tag is not working:

```
<a class="cur-pointer order button"
  data-uid="<%#Container.DataItem("unit")%>"
  data-uname="<%#Container.DataItem("UnitName")%>"
  data-price="<%#Container.DataItem("price")%>"
  data-pro-name="<%#Container.DataItem(productName)%>"
  data-iid="<%#Container.DataItem("ItemId")%>">
  <strong>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource,Order %>"></asp:Literal>
  </strong>
</a>
```

full code here :

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 0px 0px 41px 0px;">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
          <div class="sort-grid">
              <div class="col-md-4 ">
                  <div class="sorting hiddenview">
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="gridlink" runat="server" CssClass="icongridlist"><i class="gridicon"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="listlink" runat="server" CssClass="icongridlist"><i class="fa fa-list" style="color:#fff;"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                  <div class="sorting pagingdropdownmob">
                      <%-- style="width: 91px;"--%>
                      <h6>Show</h6>
                      <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownlist" Style="width: 42px;" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbtnFirst_Click">
                          <%--AppendDataBoundItems = "true"--%>
                          <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="15" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="30" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="45" Value="45"></asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sorting paginglistmob">
                      <h6>Page:&nbsp;</h6>
                      <%--  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnFirst" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnFirst_Click" ></asp:LinkButton> &nbsp;--%>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnPrevious" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnPrevious_Click"><i class="fa fa-caret-left hoverclr"></i></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
   <span>
       <asp:DataList ID="dlPaging" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="dlPaging_ItemCommand"
           OnItemDataBound="dlPaging_ItemDataBound" Style="display: inline-block;">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPaging" runat="server" Style="color: #000;" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PageIndex") %>'
                   CommandName="Paging" Text='<%# Eval("PageText") %>'></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:DataList>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnNext" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
           OnClick="lbtnNext_Click"><i class="fa fa-caret-right hoverclr"></i></asp:LinkButton></span>
                      <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnLast" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnLast_Click">Last</asp:LinkButton></span>--%>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
      </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<div class="row">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="single-pro">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phItem" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptItem" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 product-men">
                    <%--    col-md-4 col-sm-6--%>
                    <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <div class="men-thumb-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <img alt="" class="pro-image-front" src="<%#Container.DataItem("ImageSrc")%>">
                                <img alt="" class="pro-image-back" src="<%#Container.DataItem("ImageSrc")%>">
                            </a>
                            <div class="men-cart-pro" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
                                <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server"><a href="<%#Container.DataItem("ImageSrc")%>" class="link-product-add-cart image-link"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i> &nbsp;View</a></asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <%--men thumb item--%>
                        <div class="item-info-product ">
                            <h5 style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 900; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; height: 42px; line-height: 17px;" class="m-none h-initial"><strong><%#Container.DataItem(productName)%></strong></h5>
                            <%--height:33px;--%>
                            <div class="info-product-price">
                                <strong><span class="item_price"><%#Container.DataItem("price")%> </span><%=GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Currency")%><span> /<%#Container.DataItem("UnitName")%></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details item_add single-item link-product-add-cart ">
                                <a class="cur-pointer order button" data-uid="<%#Container.DataItem("unit")%>" data-uname="<%#Container.DataItem("UnitName")%>" data-price="<%#Container.DataItem("price")%>" data-pro-name="<%#Container.DataItem(productName)%>" data-iid="<%#Container.DataItem("ItemId")%>"><strong>
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource,Order %>"></asp:Literal></strong>  </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <%-- item info product--%>
                    </div>
                    <%-- menproitem--%>
                </div>
                <%--colmd3--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
  <div class="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the Repeater is in an UpdatePanel, you need to rebind the data attributes after Async PostBack. Because the PostBack updates the UI and previous bindings are lost.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bindDataAttributes();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        bindDataAttributes();
    });

    function bindDataAttributes() {
        //call the jquery function that binds data-uid etc here
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to populate the repeater on each postback. The best place for this is the `OnInit` event.